# Is there a way to install openjdk-8-jdk in a specific location in docker with ubuntu?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, java-8

I need to run an app that needs openjdk-8 in /usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-8-jdk/ but the default instalation is /usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-8-jdk-amd64/.

Is there a way to change the location orr install it again in this specific location?

Comment: Create a symlink?

Comment: I tried and it doesn't recognize the symlink for some reason